# Excel 2013 VBA Resize not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing an Excel sheet with some buttons that run VBA.
each button essentially picks a cell at the beginning of the range that it will eventually use, a length(number of cells that will be used), and a couple of other parameters entered by the user, and then sends the information to a sub, which resizes the Range that currently contains one cell to the number of cells entered in the length

When I use

```
Sub GetFromCTLGX(RangeToFill As Range, Name, TagName, TagLength)
RangeToFill = RangeToFill.Resize(1, TagLength)
```

my Range, "RangeToFill" is not changed at all.

If I use

```
Sub GetFromCTLGX(RangeToFill As Range, Name, TagName, TagLength)
RangeToFill.Resize(1, TagLength)
```

the code faults and doesn't compile.

has anyone else run into this problem?
am I missing something?

Comment: What error are you getting? What line is having the issue?

Comment: @guitarthrower, I wasn't getting an error at all on the first way of doing it. It didn't make any sense. It was just running past the line without resizing the range, it turned out that it just needed a Set put before the resize.

The second method would say that it was expecting an '=' before the RangeToFill.Resize command, it was weird, since that seems to be the common way of doing it in most examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake in my code,

it should have been

```
Set RangeToFill= RangeToFill.Resize(1, TagLength)
```

it's odd though.... it still doesn't explain to me why just

```
RangeToFill.Resize(1, TagLength)
```

wasn't working, that's what is used in a majority of the examples I saw.
I'm surprised that there wasn't an error for not having the Set keyword there.

Answer (score 0):

This example resizes the RangeToFill to extend it by one row and one column.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193274%28v=office.15%29.aspx

```
numRows = RangeToFill.Rows.Count 
numColumns = RangeToFill.Columns.Count 
Set RangeToFill = RangeToFill.Resize(numRows + 1, numColumns + 1)
```

Easily adaptable to your code

Comment: You can see that this was one of my attempts in my original code, except that I used a literal for the number of rows. I don't understand why it didn't work, but as soon as I put a "Set" in front of the third line of your example, it worked.